# asp.net mvc4 EF5 Singleton?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a project going on and I'd like to have one unique instance of a class.

I have a 'JobOffer' class, which has a property of type 'OfferStatus' (which is abstract and implements a state pattern). I have 'StateAvailable' and 'StateUnavailable' (or 'open' and 'closed' if you wish).
The 'JobOffer' objects have to be stored in the db.

I'd like to have just one 'StateAvailable' and one 'StateUnavailable', so when I create a new JobOffer I reference to 'StateAvailable' or 'StateUnavailable', and then I could list all the jobOffers which are Open (available) and all that are Closed (unavailable).

I know that I could do this by adding the states in the db in the seed method, and never instantiate a new state.
But I was wondering if it is possible to do a singleton or something to avoid that somebody (I mean controller, model or anything) can create new instances of that class.

```
public class JobOffer {
public int JobOfferId {get;set;}
public OfferState State {get;set;
public virtual ICollection<Person> People {get;set;}

//And some methods here, which depends on the state
//ie, this.State.myMethod();
```

Comment: do you have some code of JobOffer , please post it

Comment: Why don't you simply make it a Boolean and call it StateAvailable?  When unavailable it will be false, when available true.

Comment: Yes, I indeed thought of that, but it's for a college project and the teachers stated very clear that it should be a state pattern, just in case it could be scalable. I mean, today we have open and closed states, but maybe tomorrow we can have 'pending' state, or something. So that's why ;)

Comment: One of the worst things to do is to forcibly apply a design pattern when it's not needed. Especially when learning about patterns. The patterns should be applied if you recognize a problem solvable by a known pattern. In your case here, an OfferState enum is more than enough to handle future states. Don't complicate things no matter what some teachers say. They don't code and they don't have to MAINTAIN code for a living :D

Comment: Yes, I kow, but I have to finish the project and send it to them. And they want it to be a state pattern.
I mean, if I don't use a state pattern they **will** take points out of my work. This is for a final exam, so kinda need a nice score :)

Comment: That's the reason I hate school.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to use a boolean. Then you said you have to be able to expand to have more states, so I thought of an enum. Then you said you have this requirement to use a class, so... here's a little something I use when I want an enum with more smarts. You could call it a sort of "enumerating class", I suppose. So, your `OfferState` class looks like this:

```
public sealed class OfferState
{
    public bool CanChangeState { get; set; }
    //whatever properties you need

    public static OfferState Available = new OfferState(true);
    public static OfferState Unavailable = new OfferState(true);
    public static OfferState Closed = new OfferState(false);
    //whatever states you need

    public OfferState(bool canChange)
    {
        CanChangeState = canChange;
    }
}
```

This acts kind of like an enum, but it has properties like a class. So in your logic, you can check state:

```
if (jobOffer.State == OfferState.Available)
{
    //stuff
}
```

You can also get properties off it, so you can use it to get information about the state:

```
jobOffer.ExpiryDate = jobOffer.CreationDate.Add(OfferState.Available.MaxDuration);
```

And of course, the `static` nature of the various states will ensure that there's only ever one instance of each.

Comment: Thanks anaximander, but it has to have a different class for each state. I currently have abstract class 'state', 'available' class and 'unavailable' class wich both inherits from 'state'. State defines some methods that each child overrides.
In a way, your idea kind of solve it, however I am forced to use a different class for each state and the jobOffer class needs to have a state (and as the jobOffer have to be stored in the db, EF forces me to make 'state' class persistant). I only want (need) to have one object of every state, not in a class but in the entire system... Any other ideas?

Comment: Huh... this is why using a pattern for the sake of it is bad. You can make your inherited state classes entirely static, I guess; you might not be able to wrap them up in the parent class but then at least you know there would just be the one. Not 100% sure how you'd link them to job offers in a way that EF likes.